# iOS: NSPredicate for "@count == 0" for both to-one and to-many relationships

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I'd like to write a single `NSPredicate` that would work for both to-one and to-many relationships:

1) I have an `NSMutableArray` that will run the `filterUsingPredicate` method 
2) The NSPredicate will filter out a selected relationship that contain any objects in the relationship (again, for both to-one and to-many relationships).

I've tried something like `predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipObjects.@count == 0"`, but this only seems to work for to-many relationships. Is there a similar predicate format that will work for both to-one and to-many relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use check for **nil** here.

```
predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipOject != nil"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Maybe I was unclear, but I'd like the filter to keep the relationships that ARE nil. However, if I use "relationshipObject == nil", it only works for to-one relationships. I'm currently trying @"(relationshipObject == nil) OR (relationshipObject.@count == 0)" but it causes an error because a to-one NSManagedObject doesn't respond to @count.

Comment: I went ahead and used an NSCompoundPredicate to separate the predicate into two parts depending on the relationship type (to-one or to-many). This works.

Comment: powetoold can you post what you did?

Comment: predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipOject != nil" is not working for my to-one relationship :(

Comment: Mine didn't work because I was using cache for my NSFetchedResultsController. It helped to change the name of the cache.     NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"NewCacheName123"];